# Redirection option for Mediaelement.js in WordPress 3.6

Tags: wordpress, video, mediaelement.js

I'm using the new Mediaelement.js in the WP 3.6.1 core to embed H.264 video.
Now I'd like to add a redirect after the video has played.

I know there's this option (EventListener "played") in Mediaelement but don't know how to apply it.

I've done some research about the de-registration and re-registration of the .js-File but am stuck at this point.

Maybe someone can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We did have the same problem. On our case the video started automatically. So we knew when the video ended. We therefore went over to do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( window ).load(function() {
window.setTimeout(function() {window.location = "/about-us";}, 6000);
});
</script>
```

In our case the video was 6 seconds long. Afterwards we redirect to /about-us. Maybe this solution would work in your case too. Even thou it is not the exact answer to your question.